# Bring colors of SKUS products that are similar Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am listing similar sku on the product page and would like to get their colors as well.

E.g;

1-) Sku code : 21.127.21 Color : Red

2-) Sku code : 21.127.23 Color : Blue

3-) Sku code : 21.127.24 Color : Black

I probably need to update my query but I'm not sure

Following my code: `functions.php`

```
function wc_get_products_sku_img( $sku_excerpt ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Get all product Ids and skus (standard objects) from a sku excerpt
    return $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT p.ID as id, pm.meta_value as sku
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta pm
            ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_sku'
        AND pm.meta_value LIKE '%s'
        ", '%'.$sku_excerpt.'%' ) );
}
```

```
global $product;
$results = wc_get_product_skus('21.127.');

foreach ( $results as $result ) {
    $product_id  = $result->id;
    $product_sku = $result->sku;
    $product     = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    echo 'Sku Code :'. $product_sku; 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this product with variations ?

Comment: I am sharing an image for you, I dynamically change the Skular with its photo and I want to print its value next to the place where the color is written when I hover over the image.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what the problem is, I'd like to share the solution in case someone needs it.
I joined the color property in my result value and called it.

```
global $product;
$results = wc_get_product_skus('21.127.');

foreach ( $results as $result ) {
    $product_id  = $result->id;
    $product_sku = $result->sku;
    $product_color = $result->pa_color;
    $product     = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    echo 'Sku Code :'. $product_sku; 
    echo 'Sku Color :'. $product_color;

}
```